# What can I classify with 1 layer neural network?

Tags: regression, neural-networks

Assume that we are using 1 layer neural network described as a system of a equation:

$$b = f(x)$$

Where $x$ is a vector of dimension $\Re^n$ and $b$ is a vector of dimension $\Re^m$ We know the function $f()$ and it's a matrix of $\Re^{m x n}$.

Assume that $x$ is a vector from an image and $b$ is the identity number of that image. When I apply the picture $x$ into the matrix $f()$, i will receive the indentity number $b$. It's classification.

But what can I classify with 1 layer neural network if $x$ is a vector from an image?

- Can I classify simple shapes such as square, rectangular, triangle, circle?
- Can I classify the majority color?
- Can I classify patterns?
- Can I classify amout of colors?

I'm not talking about a 1 layer neural network that can classify ALL things at the same time. I'm talking about 1 layer neural network that are specified in classify certain subjects. For example:

- Layer 1 classify ONLY shapes
- Layer 2 classify ONLY majority color
- Layer 3 classify ONLY patters
- Layer 4 classify ONLY amount of colors

Combine these results from these 4 different models can give me a result of what they together see. Is that possible?

**Question:**

What can I classify with 1 layer neural network?

Comment: A single layer can only compute a linear function of the image data vector. This can give you a vector where each component represents the rough "amount" of a certain pattern or shape or color, but not a scalar value that "names" the predominant pattern/shape/color.

Comment: @Karl Yes. That's what I'm looking for. A 1 layer neural network that can classify ultra simple fundamental things such as geometrical shape, color, is it long, short, wide, far, tall etc or 1 layer neural network that can give information if it's a pattern of squares, lines, sick sack etc.